# maven commands -U and -P description

Tags: maven

I am new to maven .The following is the maven command is used in my Project.

Call `mvn -U -o clean -Dmaven.test.skip=true install -P dev`.

Can anyone please describe what -U , -p and dev does exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-P` means that you run maven profile, in this case this is `dev` profile. See [this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).
From Maven site:

> Profiles can be explicitly specified using the **-P CLI** option.
>
> This option takes an argument that is a comma-delimited list of
>   profile-ids to use. When this option is specified, no profiles other
>   than those specified in the option argument will be activated.

`-U`

> --update-snapshots                  Forces a check for updated releases and snapshots on remote repositories

Good advice is write in console write `mvn --help`.